# xml parsing with php error

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I can't find anything useful on google nor on here.
I have trouble with parsing my xml file.

```
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load('racunixml.xml');
    $searchNode = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "racun" ); 
    foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode ) 
    {   
       $xmlNaruc=$searchNode->getElementsByTagName('narucitelj');
       $valNaruc = $xmlNaruc->getAttribute('naziv'); 
       $valID = $searchNode->getAttribute('redbr'); 
       $valDate = $searchNode->getAttribute( "date" ); 
        $valPaci = $searchNode->getAttribute( "pacijent"); 
    }
```

Returns this error referring to line:
`$valNaruc = $xmlNaruc->getAttribute('naziv');`

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute()

Comment: You are not defining `xmlNaruc` anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

if you're calling ::getElementsByTagName() (pay attention at "s" in it - plural) it always returns DOMNodeList. And it hints you politely with the error message. And if we look at manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php this class doesn't have ::getAttribute() method. But DOMNode has and what you need to do here is to loop through the results returned by getElementsByTagName() in a foreach:

```
foreach($searchNode->getElementsByTagName('narucitelj') as $xmlNaruc) {
    $valNaruc = $xmlNaruc->getAttribute('naziv'); 
    .....
}
```